# How to load another groovy script in the same Jenkins node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When loading a pipeline script from another pipeline script, the two pipelines don't get executed on the same node : the first one is executed on my master node and the second gets executed on a slave node.

I'm using Jenkins pipelines with `Pipeline Script from SCM` option for a lot of jobs in this way :

- Each of my jobs defines their corresponding Git repo URL with `Poll SCM` option so that the repository gets automatically polled when a change is made to my code (basic job usage).
- Each of my jobs define a simple `Jenkinsfile` at the root of their repository, and the pipeline script inside does basically nothing but loading a more generic pipeline.

*E.g.* :

```
node {
    // --- Load the generic pipeline ---
    checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'http://github/owner/pipeline-repo.git']]]
    load 'common-pipeline.groovy'
}()
```

My *common-pipeline.groovy* pipeline does the actual stuff such as building, releasing or deploying artifacts, e.g. :

```
{ ->
    node() {
        def functions = load 'common/functions.groovy'

        functions.build()
        functions.release()
        functions.deploy()
    }
}
```

Now I **don't want to force the node for each job** so both pipelines have `node("master")` or `node("remote")` because I really don't want to be handling that manually, however I'd like that once the first pipeline runs on a specific node (either *master*, *slave1*, *slave2*, *slave3*) the second/loaded pipeline gets executed on the same node, because otherwise my actual Git repository code is not available from other node's workspace...

Is there any way I can specify that I want my second pipeline to be executed on the same node as the first, or maybe pass an argument when using the `load` step ?

Answer (score 2):

How about stashing the workspace after the checkout and before the script load?:

e.g.

```
stash includes: '**', name: "source"
```

and then unstash  it in another node(){} section:

e.g. 
`unstash "source"`

That way it will be available in the other node

Don't forget to clean up the workspace though

Or how about creating a common function that contains the logic for the checkout too (maybe passing in branches as a param). Then you can discard the node(){} in the Jenkins file and just use node(){} entries in your shared groovy script?

e.g. Jenkinsfile

```
load 'common-pipeline.groovy'
createWorlflow("*/master")
```

common-pipeline.groovy:

```
def createWorkflow(branches){
node() {
        def functions = load 'common/functions.groovy'
        functions.checkout(branches)
        functions.build()
        functions.release()
        functions.deploy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Stash/Unstash seemed like a great idea, unfortunately for some reason I can't get to my `common-pipeline` closure, the load command fails before executing common closure... Loading second script as a function is a good idea too as it will ensure me that both steps run on the same node, but checkouting inside the `createWorkflow` function means that I duplicate the checkout step (already done by Jenkins with the `Poll SCM` configuration)... I think I'm trying to combine your two solutions : calling a function and unstashing my initial workspace in my loaded function...

Comment: Actually I can never stash the code checkout from `Poll SCM` configuration because when my pipeline code is executed I am already (potentially) running code on another node, and I have no control above `Jenkins Poll SCM` execution...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a parameterized job for the second pipeline and use the parameter to control the node when triggering the second job.

The second pipeline would look like this:

```
node(runhereParam) {

}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is gonna solve my problem ? First, I don't want to have a separate triggered job because that would cause concurency issues (10 of my services running at the same time would have to wait for the second parameterized job to execute sequentially) and that is why I use pipelines, to be able to execute the same code from different jobs.

Secondly, even using your solution, where would I get the parameter `runhereParam` for the second job ? I need the two parts of my pipeline to execute on the same node !